# deleting specific tabs in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets. I want to delete all the tabs that do not have the word "ApprovedSS" in it. At present I have the following code:

```
Sub DeleteTabs()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts  = False
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If xWs.Name <> "ApprovedSS" Then
        xWs.Delete
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Can I modify this code to get the job done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this, which tests for equivalence (or the negation thereof):

```
If xWs.Name <> "ApprovedSS" Then
    xWs.Delete
End If
```

Try this, which tests whether the worksheet's name *contains* `"ApprovedSS"`:

```
If Instr(xWs.Name, "ApprovedSS") > 0 Then
    xWS.Delete
End If
```

To handle multiple sheets, first build a delimited list of sheetnames which you intend to keep, split that in to an array, and then use the `Match` function to test each sheetname for existence in the array.

This tests for *exact match* of the listed sheetnames in `KEEP_LIST` variable.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteSheets()
Dim KEEP_LIST As String
Dim keepSheets
Dim ws As Worksheet

KEEP_LIST = "ApprovedSS,ApprovedRT" '## Add items to this list, separated by comma
keepSheets = Split(KEEP_LIST, ",")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'You can't delete the last sheet in a book, so don't even try.
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count = 1 Then Exit For
    ' if the sheetname doesn't exist in our KEEP_LIST,
    ' then we delete this worksheet
    If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, keepSheets, False)) Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to have multiple names? For eg. if I wanted ApprovedSS and ApprovedRT to be kept and all other tabs to be deleted.

Comment: for example, would    `If Instr(xWs.Name, "ApprovedSS")>0 And If Instr(xWs.Name, "ApprovedRT")>0 Then`    work in this case?

Comment: You're on the right track,let me make a revision to handle multiple items... will update in a few minutes.

Comment: I tried running the code, but I ran into an issue, there are other tabs on the sheet that have "Approved"on it like "ApprovedDD" or "ApprovedGG". However I only want the tabs named "ApprovedSS" or "Approved RT" to kept and rest every tab to be deleted.

Comment: Updated, but the new method will test for exact matching sheet names, not if sheet "contains" the substring `"ApprovedSS"`, etc. as originally requested. It seems from your comment you need to test exact match for several list items.

Comment: At present my workbook has over 15 sheets, all of which contain the words "Approved". Eg. CY15_ApprovedFF_Effec100115, CY15_ApprovedPA_Effec100115 etc. I only wanted the sheets which contained the word "ApprovedFF" or "ApprovedPA" to be kept and the remaining to be deleted. This is because only the "ApprovedFF/PA" part doesn't change over the years. Hope this helps.

Comment: It would help if you were more clear in describing what you actually need, from the beginning. In your recent comment you specifically said  *tabs **named** "Approved SS" or "Approved RT"*, which implies exact matching You did not say tabs *containing* those substrings. But, now you have literally all of the pieces needed to work this out on your own. You will need to figure out how to combine the `Instr` with the `KEEP_LIST` (hint: it's going to be a double-loop).